# Insert new row using data returned by SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, insert-into

I have seen similar posts on this but have not found my exact issue and an answer. What I am trying to do is update a table with data from a variables and from data from a select statement.

For instance:

```
--THESE ARE THE VARIABLES I WANT TO USE IN INSERT

DECLARE @Key uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Name varchar(200)

SET @Key = NEWID()
SET @Name = 'TestName'

--THIS IS A TEMP TABLE THAT I WANT TO SELECT FROM AND USE THE DATA FROM THERE AND    INSERT
SELECT * FROM #TempData AS td

--THE INSERT STATEMENT
INSERT INTO MyTable(CustomerKey, Name, City, State)
VALUES(@Key, @Name, td.City, td.State)
```

Now for the `SELECT` statement, I was going to use variables for the column names like:

```
SELECT @City = City, @State = State FROM #TempData
```

But the only problem, or rather annoying is that the actual temp table has easily 40 columns in it. I really don't want to declare 40+ variables and assign it to each column.

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just simply doing..

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(CustomerKey, Name, City, State)
SELECT @Key, @Name, City, State FROM #TempData
WHERE ....
```

Basically you can scale this out for any number of columns in TempData and not have to declare variables for it.

Comment: Scott thanks for the time to reply and apologize for the delay in response. I ended up doing something very similar to what you posted. Thanks again for the answer.